# ShouldBeEquivalentTo with Exclude and case insensitivity comparison

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I want to use `ShouldBeEquivalentTo()` of fluent Assertion, by excluding few properties and making it an case insensitive comparison. For ex. I am comparing below 2 objects admin and lookUp by excluding `LastModifiedDate` and the `County` comparison should be case insensitive. Currently i am excluding it for the condition to work out but actually it should be a case insensitive comparison for `County`.

```
admin.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(
          lookUp,
          l => l.Excluding(a => a.GroupId)
     .Excluding(a => a.LastModifiedDate)
     .Excluding(a => a.County));
```

Please Suggest!

Answer (score 0):

The FluentAssertion string comparison is already case-insensitive.